# MutationObserver and window.onresize never stop, even when the job is done

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm not really familiar with this type of functions (MutationObserver and maybe more ...).
I thought I could be saved by setting setTimeout, but no, it's looping on the this._Resizing method and I have no idea to understand or solve this problem.

the idea is to keep the same display scale on the SVG, even if the window changes size, same if it is done by a script.Change windows size at first (size is 50%, and click button for toggle sizing 100 / 200 px)

If I use a JS object, it is precisely to be able to multiply it, because it is precisely one of the principles of object programming.

The code here is only to illustrate my problem and this button is only to illustrate it: it is the principle of the examples.

In my real interface there are no buttons, but other elements that can change size and may interfere with the size left for the different elements SVG.

Here is the object of the offense:

```js
const vBxEnum = Object.freeze({ "left": 0, "top": 1, "width": 2, "height": 3 });

class SVG_kit {
  constructor(zID_SVG) {

    this.$_SVG = document.getElementById(zID_SVG);
    this._viewBox = this.$_SVG.getAttribute("viewBox").split(' ').map(v => +v);
    this.svg_rect = this.$_SVG.getBoundingClientRect();

    this._scale = this._viewBox[vBxEnum.width] / this.svg_rect.width;

    // do same ratio for height                    
    this._viewBox[vBxEnum.height] = this.svg_rect.height * this._scale;
    this.$_SVG.setAttribute("viewBox", this._viewBox.join(' '));

    this.TimeOutResize = 0;
    this.count = 0;           // just to see resize infinite loop in action !

    window.onresize = e => this._Resizing();

    let observer4Size = new MutationObserver(m => this._Resizing());

    observer4Size.observe(this.$_SVG, { attributes: true });
  }

  _Resizing() {
    this.TimeOutResize = setTimeout(function (thisObj) {
      console.log('resiz', ++thisObj.count); // resize never stop !

      thisObj.svg_rect = thisObj.$_SVG.getBoundingClientRect();

      thisObj._viewBox[vBxEnum.width] = thisObj.svg_rect.width * thisObj._scale;
      thisObj._viewBox[vBxEnum.height] = thisObj.svg_rect.height * thisObj._scale;

      thisObj.$_SVG.setAttribute("viewBox", thisObj._viewBox.join(' '));

      clearTimeout(thisObj.TimeOutResize);
    }, 100, this);
  }
} /// SVG_kit

var
  svg_SZ    = '100px',
  svg_E1    = document.getElementById('First-SVG'),
  Sz_Button = document.getElementById("Bt-ChgSize");

var First_SVG = new SVG_kit('First-SVG');

Sz_Button.onclick = function ()
{
  svg_E1.style.width = svg_SZ;
  svg_SZ = (svg_SZ === '100px') ? '200px' : '100px';
}
```

```css
svg {
  margin: 1em;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em #CCC;
  background-color: #8ed1d6;
}
```

```html
<button id='Bt-ChgSize'>change Size (100px / 200px)</button>

<svg id="First-SVG" viewBox="0 0 1820 480">
  <circle fill="#F7941E" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="10" cx="250" cy="250" r="200" opacity="0.6" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running yourself into a corner with this code.

`MutationObserver` observers a DOM element and all its children for changes in either elements being moved/added/removed, or attributes being changed.

On initialization, you are watching your SVG container using one, and checking for its attributes. On change of anything, you'll call `Resizing()`.

However, inside `Resizing`, on this line:

```
  thisObj.$_SVG.setAttribute("viewBox", thisObj._viewBox.join(' '));
```

You are changing an attribute of your SVG container, which then calls `Resizing` again, and the cycle repeats.

Honestly, a `MutationObserver` for this is both overkill and unnecessary. You're perfectly fine just binding an `onResize` on its own and handling the event from there (which you did), but since **you really want one**, here is the code below:

```js
const vBxEnum = Object.freeze({ "left": 0, "top": 1, "width": 2, "height": 3 });

class SVG_kit {
  constructor(zID_SVG) {

    this.$_SVG = document.getElementById(zID_SVG);
    this._viewBox = this.$_SVG.getAttribute("viewBox").split(' ').map(v => +v);
    this.svg_rect = this.$_SVG.getBoundingClientRect();

    this._scale = this._viewBox[vBxEnum.width] / this.svg_rect.width;

    // do same ratio for height                    
    this._viewBox[vBxEnum.height] = this.svg_rect.height * this._scale;
    this.$_SVG.setAttribute("viewBox", this._viewBox.join(' '));

    this.TimeOutResize = 0;
    this.count = 0;           // just to see resize infinite loop in action !
    this._width = null;
    window.onresize = e => this._Resizing();
    let observer4Size = new MutationObserver(this._checkStyleChange.bind(this));

    observer4Size.observe(this.$_SVG, { attributes: true });
  }
  _checkStyleChange(mutations) {
    let callResizing = false;
    var element = this.$_SVG;
    var oldWidth = this._width;
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
     if (mutation.target === element && mutation.attributeName === 'style') {
       if (oldWidth !== element.style.width) {
         oldWidth = element.style.width;
         callResizing = true;
        }
      }
    });
    if (callResizing) this._Resizing();
  }

  _Resizing() {
  console.log("Resizing");
  let thisObj = this;

      thisObj.svg_rect = thisObj.$_SVG.getBoundingClientRect();

      thisObj._viewBox[vBxEnum.width] = thisObj.svg_rect.width * thisObj._scale;
      thisObj._viewBox[vBxEnum.height] = thisObj.svg_rect.height * thisObj._scale;

      thisObj.$_SVG.setAttribute("viewBox", thisObj._viewBox.join(' '));

      clearTimeout(thisObj.TimeOutResize);
  }
} /// SVG_kit

var
  svg_SZ    = '100px',
  svg_E1    = document.getElementById('First-SVG'),
  Sz_Button = document.getElementById("Bt-ChgSize");

var First_SVG = new SVG_kit('First-SVG');

Sz_Button.onclick = function ()
{
  svg_E1.style.width = svg_SZ;
  svg_SZ = (svg_SZ === '100px') ? '200px' : '100px';
//  First_SVG._Resizing();
}
```

```css
svg {
  margin: 1em;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em #CCC;
  background-color: #8ed1d6;
}
```

```html
<button id='Bt-ChgSize'>change Size (100px / 200px)</button>

<svg id="First-SVG" viewBox="0 0 1820 480">
  <circle fill="#F7941E" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="10" cx="250" cy="250" r="200" opacity="0.6" />
</svg>
```

Comment: @MrJ Why not? What prevents you from calling `_Resizing` straight from the `onClick`? You already have all the info required at that point, you don't need the observer.

Comment: @MrJ added a snippet to prove to you that the observer is completely unnecessary and easily replaced by a direct call to `_Resizing()`.

Comment: Then why did you not say so in your question? Your question has absolutely __zero mention__ of this, neither in the code nor in the actual description. All you've said is: there is a button to modify the size, there is an `onresize` (because the element width is variable on start).

Comment: @MrJ changed the snippet, brought back the `MutationObserver` since you seem to really want it. No longer gets into an infinite loop and can take direct style changes from the outside (which goes against every OO principle out there, but, you know, at the end of the day, I can only answer your question, not tell you that you're on step 1 towards building an unmaintainable mess)

Comment: But this only work for width changing, I suppose I have to add for the Height case too.

Comment: Combine it in the observer.